# Firebase Google Auth doesn't work in Kitkat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-4.4-kitkat, google-authentication

I integrated many Firebase services and wonderfully works well. But, Google Auth doesn't works in **kitkat**(only) resulting an resultCode '0' while Auth reply from Google on onActivityResult().

Firebase and Google service libs are latest.
Any input would be highly appreciated.